# HttpResponseException issue with Titanium appcelerator

Tags: java, android, titanium, httpresponse

I am getting the following error message when I am generating the apk with my code.

```
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient: (TiHttpClient-1) [2663,2663] HTTP Error 

(org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException): Unauthorized
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$LocalResponseHandler.handleResponse(TiHTTPClient.java:275)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$LocalResponseHandler.handleResponse(TiHTTPClient.java:219)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:637)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$ClientRunnable.run(TiHTTPClient.java:1334)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

My configuration :

- SDK version 3.5.0
- OS: Ubuntu 14.03
- Titanium Studio, build: 3.4.1

Comment: Source snippet?  Looks like you called a web function incorrectly or it doesn't exist.  Did you use the right method call?  POST, maybe GET?

Comment: What URL are you attempting to hit?

Comment: Having the same issue. Wonder if you managed to pin it down?